# setVisibility(view.GONE) is not working Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

i need to disable the view  programmatically so i  used setVisibility(view.GONE) in activity. My  xml have two buttons named lower and upper and two relative layouts named lower_lay and upper_lay.when i click the lower button i need enable lower_lay and i click the upper button i need to enable upper_lay. Both in upeer_lay and lower_lay having images and performing onTouch event. Now my problem is when i am in lower_lay the images of upper_lay are disabled but when i touch the empty space in lower_lay, upper_lay images are coming...and in upper_lay i am having this issue. Why the view is not completelt gone?

i am trying this from 3 days....please any one help me out.

xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"

  >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1e356a">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placce_head"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Hyderabad to banglore"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />



    </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#78869c"
                android:weightSum="2"

                android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seats"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Selected Seats"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalamount"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Total Amount"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#78869c"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/seat_num"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_amount"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:background="#1e356a"
              >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1e356a"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bluesmall"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:text="Available"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/greensmall"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Selected"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"

                    android:src="@drawable/pinksmall"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ladies"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"/>
                <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/redsmall"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="Booked"/>


                </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                   android:id="@+id/sleeper_lay"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:background="#78869c"
                   android:weightSum="2"

                   android:padding="7dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   >
                   <Button
                       android:id="@+id/lower"
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="Lower"
                       android:textColor="#F93249"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:textSize="18dp"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                   <Button
                       android:id="@+id/upper"
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="Upper"
                       android:textSize="18dp"
                       android:textColor="#ffffff"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

               </LinearLayout>





            <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >






    </RelativeLayout>
               <RelativeLayout
                   android:id="@+id/relative_layout_two"

                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/bg_border"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:gravity="center" >






               </RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done_btn"
    android:background="#F93249"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="done"/>

           </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Activitiy:

```
lower_lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);//lower layout
       upper_lay= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_two);//upperlayout
    upper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           lower_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            upper.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F93249"));
            lower.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            upper_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            sheetdetails.clear();

        }
    });

    lower.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         upper_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            upper.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            lower.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F93249"));
           lower_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Where do you initialize relative_layout_two ?

Comment: @IgorB  please see my edited post. i intialized those layouts

Comment: I still can't see it.

Comment: This weird happens, seems like everything ok. Did you debug listeners ? Are upper and  lower clicklisteners called?

Comment: yes, they are calling properly. view is invisible to me. not completely gone. when i touch the screen those layout view are coming. overlapping is the problem

Comment: Could you show whole XML, I need to see parent view

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
`View.GONE`
not 
`view.GONE`

and `lower.setOnClickListener` not `lower.setOnTouchListener`

Answer (score 0):

`View` is the class, so should starts with capital letter.
Kindly see my updates.

```
upper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lower_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        upper.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F93249"));
        lower.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        upper_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});

lower.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lower_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        upper.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        lower.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F93249"));
        upper_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```